# Best practices to identify users in Gmail API?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

The [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/modify) uses a UserId which is the user email address. However, an email address is [not a reliable identified](https://spaces.at.internet2.edu/display/federation/why-is-email-not-an-appropriate-user-identifier) over the time. On Google Workspace, it is frequent that user email addresses are changed.

What are the best practices to connect (and remain connected) to a specific user mailbox over the long run?

Note: on the [directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#User), Google actually uses an "id" for a user which does not change.

Comment: People api will give you user profile information

Comment: Thanks but I don't get it. Could you elaborate your answer?

Comment: If your application allows users to sign in with Google, you can use the 'sub' claim in the ID token, which represents the unique Google ID of the authenticated user. This ID is stable and not subject to email address changes.

Answer (score 0):

In this implementation with axios and typescript....

```
import axios from 'axios';

const googleApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com',
  // Configure other Axios settings as needed
});

async function getUserImmutableId(email: string, accessToken: string): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const response = await googleApi.get(`/admin/directory/v1/users/${email}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });

    return response.data.id; // The immutable user ID
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching user ID:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

// Example usage
const userEmail = 'user@example.com';
const userAccessToken = 'your_oauth_access_token_here'; // Ensure this token has the necessary scopes

getUserImmutableId(userEmail, userAccessToken)
  .then(userId => {
    console.log(`The immutable ID for ${userEmail} is ${userId}`);
    // Use userId with Gmail API here
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

... you got Axios Configuration, OAuth2 Authorization, Error Handling, and Immutable User IDs these are the most important best practices that are on the top of my head.

Comment: What if I receive a notification from the Gmail (with only the email address)? This is how the Gmail API works.